# Copy & paste values using google sheet api

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I want to copy `"'data'!A2:D2"` to `"'data'!K2:N2"` but I'm getting the following error. The script works with the batch update but cannot work it out with copy and pasting.

```
{"error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"requests\": Cannot find field.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
        "fieldViolations": [
          {
            "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"requests\": Cannot find field."
          }]}]}}
```

The code I'm using.

```
import json
import gspread
import requests
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scope = [
    "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
]

creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("creds.json", scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)
sh = client.open("kite")

spreadsheet_id = sh.id
sheet_id = sh.worksheet("data").id

headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + creds.get_access_token().access_token,
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
}

reqs = [
    {
        "copyPaste": {
            "source": {
                "sheetId": sheet_id,
                "startRowIndex": 1,
                "endRowIndex": 2,
                "startColumnIndex": 0,
                "endColumnIndex": 4,
            },
            "destination": {
                "sheetId": sheet_id,
                "startRowIndex": 1,
                "endRowIndex": 2,
                "startColumnIndex": 10,
                "endColumnIndex": 14,
            },
            "pasteType": "PASTE_VALUES",
            "pasteOrientation": "NORMAL",
        }
    }
]

r = requests.post(
    f"https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheet_id}/values:batchUpdate",
    headers=headers,
    data=json.dumps({"requests": reqs}),
)
```

Reference:
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#CopyPasteRequest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The copyPaste request can be used with spreadsheets.batchUpdate method. So, when your script is modified, please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
f"https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheet_id}/values:batchUpdate",
```

#### To:

```
f"https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheet_id}:batchUpdate",
```

#### Note:

- In your script, gspread is used. When gspread is used, your script can be also modified as follows.

  ```
    client = gspread.authorize(creds)
    sh = client.open("kite")
    sheet_id = sh.worksheet("data").id
    reqs = [
        {
            "copyPaste": {
                "source": {
                    "sheetId": sheet_id,
                    "startRowIndex": 1,
                    "endRowIndex": 2,
                    "startColumnIndex": 0,
                    "endColumnIndex": 4,
                },
                "destination": {
                    "sheetId": sheet_id,
                    "startRowIndex": 1,
                    "endRowIndex": 2,
                    "startColumnIndex": 10,
                    "endColumnIndex": 14,
                },
                "pasteType": "PASTE_VALUES",
                "pasteOrientation": "NORMAL",
            }
        }
    ]
    res = sh.batch_update({"requests": reqs})
  ```

#### Reference:

- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)